# Firebase Realtime Databse orderByChild not working in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Realtime database orderByChild not working in my Flutter Application.

I have a database structure like this

[image]

and I am trying to get only online drivers and using this query.

```
PhoneFirebaseManager.getFreshFirebaseDatabase()
    .reference()
    .child("drivers")
    .orderByChild("online")
    .equalTo(true)
    .once()
    .then((DataSnapshot snap) {
  if (snap.value == null) {
    print("No driver is Available...!");
  } else {
    print("Driver is Available...!");
  }

  print(snap?.value?.toString()); // always returns null
});
```

I found it worked on the first 2,3 invocations but later after changing online status many times, it shows the same result again and again.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Aside from that: it's hard to help with a problem that can't be reliably reproduced. Can you figure out precisely when it starts giving the wrong result. It'd probably also help to know what you mean with "it shows the same result again and again". What result does it show? And why is that wrong?